# How can I replace a repeating sequence of the same element at once in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently, I have the following rule:

```
<xsl:template match="p">  

<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

The purpose of this rule to replace the element "p" by a new line. 
However, if there are several "p" following another (e.g. `<p><p><p><p>`)
they should be converted to just one new line and not multiple new lines. Is there any canonical solution for this in XSLT?

Edit:
As an example was requested:

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
```

Should be replaced by a single newline.

Comment: An example of the input, with the expected output, would be useful - see: [mcve].

Comment: That's a useless example.

Answer (score 0):

use axes to print the first 'p':

```
<xsl:template match="p">
<xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::p) = 0">
<p/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What if a `<p>` element has a preceding `<p>` sibling, but the two are not consecutive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
   <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p])">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="., following-sibling::*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p)">
         <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">&#xA;</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This seems to disable all my other templates (which do not refer to p at all). Is it possible to change it so they are still called?